# jqPlot error with graph size and background scroll in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, jqplot

The problem is when I have a lot of bars to show. I plot the graph and doesn't show the background or the descriptions but when I scroll down they appear (you can see in the images). It doesn't happen in IE or Firefox.
I detect that when I reduce the size of the graph it doesn't happen, but when I have more data to plot I have to reduce more and for that reason this solution doesn't scale.

It seems to be a chrome bug because i don't have any JavaScript error in console more than

"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. "

This is before scroll down: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0c295g64okupxnc/error%20.jpg

And this, after: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gj9iyuvzrshs9p/error%202.jpg

That's the function who draws the chart:

```
 /**
 * Creates a bar chart
 *
 * @param title
 * @param data
 * @param labelX
 * @param labelY
 */
_draw_bars: function (title, data, labelX, labelY) {
    var values = [];
    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var items = [];

    $(data).each(function(){
        var n = values.length+1;

        if (this[1] > max) {
            max = this[1];
        }

        values.push([[n, this[1]]]);
        items.push('<li >' + n + ': ' + this[0] + ' (' + this[1] + ')</li>');

    });        
    if(values.length < 15){
        this._show_modal(this._get_html(title, items,800,400),950,450);
    }else{
        this._show_modal(this._get_html(title, items,800,300),1350,650);
    }
    var barSize = this._get_bar_size(values.length);
    $.jqplot.config.defaultHeight = $(window).height()*0.5;
    $.jqplot('chart_div', values, {
        legend:{show:false},
        title: {show:false},
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection:'vertical',
                barPadding: barSize[0],
                barMargin: barSize[1]
            }
            },
        series: [],
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    label: labelY,
                    min:0,
                    max:values.length,
                    autoscale: true,
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    labelOptions: {enableFontSupport: true,
                                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                    fontSize: '12pt'                                       
                                    }

            },
            yaxis:{ 
                min:0,
                max:max,
                ticks:this._get_ticks(min, max),
                tickOptions:{formatString:'%d'},
                label: labelX,
                autoscale: true,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                labelOptions: {enableFontSupport: true, fontFamily: 'Arial',fontSize: '12pt'}

                }
        },
        highlighter: {
           show: false
         }
    });
},
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: there I add the code to the post, thanks

Comment: I've posted on questions about jqPlot a few times, and each time I've recommended that the poster uses [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) instead. jqPlot is no longer supported, and I found Flot to be much easier to use.